# How to converting this sum into integral?

Tags: integration, summation

I see the below conversion in a book but I can't quite understand how the bound or the index shifts are performed. Could someone please explain this?

$$\sum_{i=2}^{k}(h_i/f_{i-1})=\int_{1}^{k}(h(i)/f(i))di$$

Comment: For this to be an equality you would undoubtedly need to change one or both of the functions

Comment: What if we just consider it as an equivalency, I am just curious to know how the bounds and indices are shifted.

Comment: At a guess, consider a sum of values as the "height" at that point multiplied by a rectangle width of $1$. If you take the value at the end of the domain as the height you would have the $i=2$ term representing the area in the domain $(1,2)$ so when you take the integral you would want to integrate from $1$.

Comment: This is called the "Right Rectangular Approximation Method" and as a limit you could compare it to the "Right Riemann Sum"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can understand the lower bound shift. However, I still can't understand why in the integral both function have (i) as their argument.